# CanJS object list automatic subclassing and reclassing

Tags: javascript, ajax, canjs, canjs-model, canjs-list

A remote, third-party JSONP server provides my CanJS script with a list of results like this one:

```
[
    { "class": "ABaseClass", "value": "1"},
    { "class": "ASubClass", "value": "2"},
    { "class": "ABaseClass", "value": "3"},
    { "class": "ASubClass", "value": "4"}, 
    ...
]
```

where `type` is the intended object class, defined in CanJS using `can.Model.extend`:

The following simplified code demonstrates the CanJS setup:

```
ABaseClass = can.Model.extend({ ... }, {
    'findAll': { 'url': 'the url', 'dataType': "jsonp" }
    // this is modified source code and may not run
});

// ASubClass is a subclass of ABaseClass.
ASubClass = ABaseClass.extend({ ... }, { ... });
```

**Problem:**

When `ABaseClass.findAll({}, function(data) { ... })` is called, which calls the JSONP endpoints for more objects, the callback obtains a list of CanJS models, but only of class `ABaseClass`.

**Question:**

*Is there a helper method provided by CanJS to automatically create subclasses based on a field within a list of objects? If not, how can I go about implementing one?*

---

Expected output:

```
[
    (new ABaseClass(...)),
    (new ASubClass(...)),
    (new ABaseClass(...)),
    (new ASubClass(...)),
    ...
]
```

---

Environment:

- CanJS: 1.17
- jQuery: 1.10.1
- I cannot control what types of objects the endpoint returns.
- Multiple AJAX calls is not an accepted solution.

Comment: I can take a crack at it, do you expect the result of findAll to be a ABaseClass.List, can.List or js array?

Comment: @complistic I have since switched to Backbone (see date), but either one working solution you have for this question will definitely help the CanJS community.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to override the `models` method and find the correct model for the class like this:

```
ABaseClass = can.Model.extend('ABaseClass', {
    'findAll': { url: "/the_url", dataType: "jsonp" },
    models: function(results){
        return_models = new can.List();
        can.each(results, function(result){
            return_models.push( window[result.class].model(result.value) )
        })
        return return_models;
    }
}, {});

ASubClass = ABaseClass.extend('ASubClass', {}, {});

ABaseClass.findAll({}, function(results){
    console.log(results);
})
```

What this does is:

1. When the `findAll` returns it sends it's result to the `models` method.
2. The `models` method then loops over each of the results.
3. It then finds the model constructor attached to the window. ( `window[result.class]` )
4. Then we call `model` on the constructor to construct/update the model instance.
5. Add the model instance to a `can.List` and return it.

I have tested this in CanJS 2.0.x and it works fine here.

You can find more details about how this all works in the docs:

- http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.models.html
- http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.model.html

It looks like these will be Deprecated in CanJS 2.1.0 in favour of `.parseModels` and `.parseModel`

- http://www.bitovi.com/blog/2014/02/canjs-infrastructure-improvements.html#perpetual-beta-pre-releases